# QGIS 2.12 How can I assign the attributes of the polygons of the layer A containing the geometry of layer B?

Tags: qgis, spatial-analyst, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, spatial-join

In other words, I have two shapefiles:

1. Layer A: not-intersected Areas (1 attribute: ID);
2. Layer B: Buildings (Several attributes).

I want to identified by the related ID attribute all the buildings of layer B included in the area of Layer A.

If the area represents the boundary of several towns and the ID attribute represents the name of each town, I want to assign to each building an attribute representing which town they belong to.

Comment: That's called a table join. [Here's a tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html). If that doesn't fully address your question, please [edit] your question indicating what you tried and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: I think that what you're looking for is a spatial joint, research it and come back with more detail if that's didn't work for you